# Reactive forms are built around observable streams

Tags: angular

I have seen Observables being used with services to fetch data with its subscribe method.

I have also seen Reactive forms as follows:
Here `name` can be accessed in HTML and it will have the value input by user.

```
export class NameEditorComponent {
  name = new FormControl('');
}
```

From: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

> Reactive forms are built around observable streams, where form inputs and values are provided as streams of input values, which can be accessed synchronously.

What does that mean? Where in reactive forms are observables being used w.r.t form inputs?

Please explain that above quote w.r.t reactive forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstract class `AbstractControl` has a property `valueChanges`. Its an observable that mirror the value of your FormControl.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl